# Can i upload android build on google play store through API?

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am trying to upload a new android build to google play store by using API, is it possible?

Comment: [Google Play Publishing API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#publishing_api_overview)

Answer (score 1):

As per the Google Official document, you can [upload APK using API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing).

Comment: But according to API usage instruction, we can not do this.Find instruction below link, i think it's not possible. 
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api_usage

Comment: That is instruction, it not clearly mentioned you can not use api to upload app on store.